# Own styles for google map "SATELLITE"

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to add own styles for different map types id?

Currently when create styles for google map I can't display them on different map types then ROADMAP.

I would like to remove all administration labels from map type SATELLITE or HYBRIDE. I checked google maps documentation but I didn't find any information about this.

Answer (score 0):

for administrative  labels/information you can try

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     var myStyle = [
        {
          featureType: "administrative",
          elementType: "labels",
          stylers: [
           { visibility: "off" }
         ]
       }
    ]


map.setOptions({styles: myStyle});
```

Comment: Satellite normally don't have label ... is Hybrid type the one with admin label .. and use setOption .. i have update the answer with setOptions